# Pino conditional transport

Tags: node.js, pinojs

Trying to conditionally use a pino transport.  In particular pino-slack-transport.  The level is set to error, but need to conditionally send logs to the transport based upon another variable (ie environment variable which is production or development)

loggerSlackTransport.js

```
import { createTransport } from 'pino-slack-transport'
import config from './config'
const options = { webhookUrl: config.slack_alerts }

export default function transport() {
  return createTransport(options)
}
```

logger.js

```
const logger = pino(
  {
    ...
    transport: {
      targets: [
        {
          level: "error",
          target: "./loggerSlackTransport.js",
        },
      ],
    },
);
```